# android SOCKS proxy

Tags: android, socks

I have the following code in my (test) android project:

```
        URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com");

        InetSocketAddress sa = InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("127.0.0.1", 1080);
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, sa);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection(proxy);
```

Then I have implemented a SOCKS server listening on port 1080.

The problem I have is that in the SOCKS4 connection request, the destination address and port is not "ip for google":80 but rather 127.0.0.1:1080, i.e. the proxy address.

If I return ok, I start getting HTTP data.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in the SOCKS-client?

Comment: Where can i get SOCKS version 5 library to use for my android application?
Can you please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that is a little lower level but might be useful for you:

This works for me on Android 4.3 on rooted Nexus 4 with [SSHTunnel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sshtunnel&hl=en) running:

```
    SocketAddress proxyAddr = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 1984);  
    SocketAddress hostAddr = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);
    java.net.Proxy proxy = new java.net.Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxyAddr);
    socket = new Socket(proxy);
    socket.connect(hostAddr);
```

Note: I also installed [iptables beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mgranja.iptables&hl=en) but I'm not sure if it's required.

For this to work with an emulator change the IP to 10.0.2.2 which is Android's alias for your host machine.  You will have to run a local SOCKS proxy on your machine of course.